# Authorization failing with 401,while trying to access azure rest apis

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to call the inbuilt azure API by bearer token generation. The bearer token is generated using "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/token,"; and using this token, I'm trying to access the get device API from IoT Hub. The headers i am providing for the REST API call are content-type and Authorization(with the bearer token). But it is returning an error message as below:

```
Message;:;ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorized;3cc43d2f-def7-4a3e-a2ue-eb367467ab90 is not valid;
```

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, did my answer help you at all? If not, let me know if I need to clarify it more.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to your IoT Hub's Service API, you need a shared access token, not an oauth2 token. You can generate the token you need to set in your header through the `az cli`

```
az iot hub generate-sas-token -n {iothub_name}
```

If you like a more visual approach, you can use the [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/releases). You can simply enter your IoT Hub connection string with service connect or iothubowner right and generate the token.

[image: device explorer]

You can then use the service endpoints of your IoT Hub, here's an example curl request:

```
curl --request GET \
https://<hub-name>.azure-devices.net/devices?api-version=2018-06-30 \
--header "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=<hub-name>.azure-devices.net&sig=KSobATNRdkFtd999999990v7NYU4hitkTA3ts%3D&se=1626508840&skn=iothubowner"
```

Comment: @Rakesh S Please accept helpful responses as 'Answer', which will be helpful to others as well.